# Is this an error in A.Zee's 《Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell》?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

I am reading A.Zee's 《Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell》 page 44.
He is trying to evaluate $Z(J)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dq e^{-\frac{1}{2m^{2}}q^{2}-\frac{\lambda}{4!}q^{4}+Jq}$

Of the term $\propto(\frac{1}{m^{2}})^{6}\lambda^{2}J^{4}$,He draws the diagrams as below:
[image: A.Zee page 46 fig I.7.2]

My question is,did he missed this diagram?

[image]

It seems that only by including this diagram can I get the correct numerical result,but I am not quite sure whether I am right.Can somebody help me? Thank you!

Comment: See also [Errata](http://www.kitp.ucsb.edu/members/PM/zee/nuts.html) on the author's [homepage](http://www.kitp.ucsb.edu/members/PM/zee/QuantumFieldTh.html).